# User Attendence app

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Guys i have requirment and im confused. User's staffs have smart phones. Now he wants to develop an attendance app.
Requirment is when a staff mark his attendance via his mobile app he should 
be presented in the office premise. we need to **prevent** his marking attendance when he is out of the office.

I was thinking about ibeacon. but its not feasible. i thought to check if staff connected office wifi. But User was telling staff can access the wifi even from the road. Is it possible to use gps Proximity for this kind of validation?

User is requesting to do a research if there is any other way to achieve this, only via the technologies reside in the phone.

ideas welcome. (please dont tell to use finger print. this a research. finger print is alternate solution.)

Comment: GPS location can be spoofed. If the employees are not to be trusted, this is not a solution.

Comment: Yeah. we cant make sure it will work accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best solution is to use Mobile phone as a Beacon Broadcaster. It gives best solution. We need Bluetooth LTE Supporting devices for this.

Answer (score 1):

Few Solutions:

1] Store the co-ordinates of the office in and database. So when staff checks in for Attendance on the app. Locate its co-ordinates, match them, if same then enaaaaabe him to attend.

2] When app launches check for the location, if office then proceed further.

3] When staff punches in for attendance, launch a samera task to grab a selfie. See to that no gallery access. Tag the photo with time and location

Comment: ha ha..you're in my boat. But selfie doen't work since its also not secured if you think more.